# Filter and sort objects

Tags: javascript

Input data example json file:

```
{"data": [{"name": "Kyle", "email": "kyle2@mail.com"},
{"name": "Kyle", "email": "kyle1@mail.com"},
{"name": "Kate", "email": "kate@mail.com"}]}
```

Filter and sort condition example json file:

```
{"condition": {"include": [{"name": "Kyle"}], "sort_by": ["email"]}}
```

result:

```
{"result": [{"name": "Kyle", "email": "kyle1@mail.com"},
{"name": "Kyle", "email": "kyle2@mail.com"}]}
```

What should be the logic? Is .filter and .sort best way to handle this task?

```
const array = [];
const filterCondition = {}

async function fetchAsync() {
  const response = await fetch("./input.json");
  const data = await response.json();

// get array to work with

  data.data.forEach((item) => {
    array.push(item);
  });

// here I tried to get condition to the variable, so later I can use .filter method

  const filterCondition = data.condition.exclude[0];

// I understand that this is bad way... And you could also have more than one condition in that array.. 
// But how can you access that condition in the json condition file?

}

fetchAsync();
```

Also condition to filter could be "include" or "exclude". I have only idea to make
if statement like this

```
if (include) {
   array.filter(e => e.xxx === condition.xxx)
} else {
   array.filter(e => e.xxx !== condition.xxx)
}
```

Help please with the logic of realisation.

Comment: You're on the right track. I've a strong feeling that you might be able to do it on your own as you've made it this far.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for the multiple `include` and multiple `sort_by` options.

I have assumed that all values are strings when comparing. You might extend it as per your needs.

```js
const input = {
  data: [
    { name: "Kyle", code: "ASDF", email: "kyle1@mail.com", web: "kyle.com" },
    { name: "Kyle", code: "ASDF", email: "kyle1@mail.com", web: "kyle.au" },
    { name: "Kate", code: "notASDF", email: "kate@mail.com" },
  ],
};

const rule = {
  condition: {
    include: [{ name: "Kyle" }, { code: "ASDF" }],
    sort_by: ["email", "web"],
  },
};

const output = input.data
  .filter((item) =>
    rule.condition.include.every((obj) =>
      Object.entries(obj).reduce(
        (cond, [key, value]) => cond && item[key]?.includes(value),
        true
      )
    )
  )
  .sort((a, b) =>
    rule.condition.sort_by
      .map((key) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]))
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev || curr, 0)
  );

console.log(output);
```

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: you are comparing the values for exact match, I think it should be includes. `item[key] === value`

Comment: @hawks, updated the answer to use includes!

Comment: @NewBieJavaPro, let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: @Amila Senadheera, Can you please explain what this .reduce does?
".reduce((prev, curr) => prev || curr, 0)"

Comment: It does OR operation for all the output in the map operation (individual compare outputs), since email comparison output is zero  then web comparison is used. `compare email || compare web`

Answer (score 0):

It works when input and rule are in the same file. But when I fetch them, I get an error

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item[key]?.includes is not a function"

Cannot understand this. Input and rule objects are exactly the same after fetch.

```
const input = {
  data: [],
};
const rule = {};

async function fetchAsync() {
  const response = await fetch("./input.json");
  const data = await response.json();

  data.data.forEach((item) => {
    input.data.push(item);
  });

  rule.condition = data.condition;

  console.log(input);
  console.log(rule);

  const output = input.data
    .filter((item) =>
      rule.condition.include.every((obj) =>
        Object.entries(obj).reduce(
          (cond, [key, value]) => cond && item[key]?.includes(value),
          true
        )
      )
    )
    .sort((a, b) =>
      rule.condition.sort_by
        .map((key) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]))
        .reduce((prev, curr) => prev || curr, 0)
    );

  console.log(output);
}

fetchAsync();
```